# Footer at bottom with partial horizontal line

Tags: css, footer

I am using Pressbooks (to publish a book). In CSS I'm trying to turn the line above the footnotes from a full line to partial line.

My CSS skills are limited, so I've not been able to do much.

```
.footnote {
   padding-left: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   font-family: 'Lora', serif;
   font-size: 0.8888888889rem;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
   letter-spacing: normal;
   word-spacing: normal;
   color: initial;
   line-height: 1.5555555556em;
   text-align: left;
   text-indent: 0;
   text-transform: none;
   counter-increment: footnote;
   footnote-style-position: outside; }

.endnote::footnote-call, .footnote::footnote-call {
   font-size: 0.8em;
   line-height: 0.5em;
   vertical-align: top; }

p {
   prince-footnote-policy: keep-with-line; }

@page {
 @footnotes {
   border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 0.3em;
   padding-top: 0.3em; } }
```

I would like a partial line between the body and the footnotes, but this gives a full line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without seeing your HTML or some more of the CSS for the footer, we really can't help. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `font-size: 0.8888888889rem;` -- that's *oddly* specific. Have you considered `px` units of measurement? And also `prince-footnote` is not a valid value of `display`.

Comment: @disinfor Thanks! I am actually, though, still not sure what more I can provide, since this appears to be all that is there in relation to footnotes. What is there is not producing an error or problem; I am just looking to learn what I need to add/delete to make the partial line.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks for the tip!

Comment: We need the HTML. We can test what you have if we can't see it. Do a view source on your page and grab the HTML for the `.footnote`

Comment: @disinfor I don't believe this is possible with Pressbooks. The CSS I am editing is accessible in only one place, and the changes made there are applied to the whole book. The only place I can access the HTML is when I go into the individual chapters, but then there's no CSS accessible there. Does that make sense? I recognize this may leave me helpless, but I hope not! I've added from the CSS the only other mention of .footnote. For what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `border-clip` for this:

```css
@page {
  @footnotes {
    border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-clip: 3in;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
```

Doesn't look like Prince supports percentage values for `border-clip` though. See [here](https://www.princexml.com/forum/topic/537/styling-of-footnotes-area).

[image]

Here's the full code example for the above screenshot.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .footnote {
        display: prince-footnote;
        font-family: 'Lora', serif;
        font-size: 0.8888888889rem;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        word-spacing: normal;
        color: initial;
        line-height: 1.5555555556em;
        text-align: left;
        text-indent: 0;
        text-transform: none;
        counter-increment: footnote;
        footnote-style-position: outside;
      }

      @page {
        @footnotes {
          border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
          border-clip: 3in;
          padding: 0.3em 0;
          margin: 10px 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is a page title</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      <span class="footnote">This is my footnote.</span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bingo!! Thanks, Jonathan!!! I will henceforth think very favourably of paper "clips." :)